# Add Sequential Number To Javascript Objects In Nested Object Tree

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have an object like the one below and am looking for a way to add one property to each sub object in the tree. That is, I want to add a number to the object that counts up from 0 to n. I know I can traverse through the object with a recursive function but because of variable scope I'm not able to use a simple incremented variable to count up as I go through the tree.

Current Object:

```
var tree = [
{
    name: 'a',
    children: []
},{
    name: 'b',
    children: [
        {
            name: 'c',
            children: []
        }
    ]
},
{
    name: 'd',
    children: [
        {
            name: 'e',
            children: [
                {
                    name: 'f',
                    children: []
                },
                {
                    name: 'g',
                    children: []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
];
```

Desired Object:

```
var tree = [
{
    name: 'a',
    number: 0,
    children: []
},{
    name: 'b',
    number: 1,
    children: [
        {
            name: 'c',
            number: 2,
            children: []
        }
    ]
},
{
    name: 'd',
    number: 3,
    children: [
        {
            name: 'e',
            number: 4,
            children: [
                {
                    name: 'f',
                    number: 5,
                    children: []
                },
                {
                    name: 'g',
                    number: 6,
                    children: []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
];
```

Comment: If your function needs a specific value to do its work, pass it as a parameter - that eliminates all scope problems.

Comment: Or, if getting it to increment regardless of recursion level is the problem, use a variable that's in a scope above the function that gets called recursively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set counter variable outside of **recursive** function and increment it before you loop object.

```js
var tree = [{"name":"a","children":[]},{"name":"b","children":[{"name":"c","children":[]}]},{"name":"d","children":[{"name":"e","children":[{"name":"f","children":[]},{"name":"g","children":[]}]}]}];

function addNumber(input) {
  var counter = 0;

  function rec(data) {
    data.forEach(function(e) {
      if (typeof e == 'object' && !Array.isArray(e)) {
        e.number = counter++;
        for (var p in e) {
          if (typeof e[p] == 'object') rec(e[p])
        }
      } 
    })
  }
  rec(input)
}

addNumber(tree);
console.log(tree)
```

Comment: Great. Is it necessary to have the else if statement at the end of the forEach loop? Each element 'e' going into the loop is always going to be an object and not an array.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you raise with the counter scope can be solved by defining the counter in a closure, within which you also have your recursive function.

Here is an ES6 function that does that:

```js
function numberNodes(tree, n = 0) {
    return (function recurse(children) {
        return children.map( node => Object.assign({}, node, {
            number: n++,
            children: recurse(node.children)
        }) );
    })(tree);
}
// Sample data
var tree = [{ name: 'a', children: []},
            { name: 'b', children: 
                [{ name: 'c', children: []}]},
            { name: 'd', children: 
                [{ name: 'e', children: 
                    [{ name: 'f', children: []}, { name: 'g', children: []}]}]}];

// Return tree with numbers added:
tree = numberNodes(tree);

// Output result
console.log(tree);
```

Note that this function does not mutate the tree you pass it, only the return value has the added properties. So this is a *functional programming* way of doing it.

Comment: This is probably the better route to take in solving this problem though I am ok with modifying the source object in my case. Also, how the anonymous function, map function and recursive functions all interact is a little beyond me at this point, I'l need to hit the books more.